# Invalid argument: Saw a non-null label (index >= num_classes - 1) following a null label

Tags: keras, ctc

Im getting the following error while doing CTC training:

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
(0) Invalid argument:  Saw a non-null label (index >= num_classes - 1) following a null label, batch: 0 num_classes: 40 labels: 35,4,6,18,8,36,29,37,38,39,40,0 labels seen so far: 35,4,6,18,8,36,29,37,38
[[node CTC-MODEL/ctc/CTCLoss (defined at :18) ]]
(1) Invalid argument:  Saw a non-null label (index >= num_classes - 1) following a null label, batch: 0 num_classes: 40 labels: 35,4,6,18,8,36,29,37,38,39,40,0 labels seen so far: 35,4,6,18,8,36,29,37,38
[[node CTC-MODEL/ctc/CTCLoss (defined at :18) ]]
[[gradient_tape/CTC-MODEL/ctc/Shape/_72]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_12365]

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the last layer of the model, use num_classes + 1:

```
outputs = Dense(num_classes + 1, activation = 'softmax')(...)
```

Comment: Why but? we have to add extra